# How to add an element before the first element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am working on a comments system, using PHP + jQuery. I need to add the last comment to the top, before all the `div` elements. E.G.

```
<div id="comment">
<div class="comment-3"></div>
<div class="comment-2"></div>
<div class="comment-1"></div>
</div>
```

So now I want to add the new `<div class="comment-4"></div>` with jQuery to look like that:

```
<div id="comment">
<div class="comment-4"></div>
<div class="comment-3"></div>
<div class="comment-2"></div>
<div class="comment-1"></div>
</div>
```

**Edit:**
NOTE: I am using:

```
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST", url: "ajax.php", cache : false, data: goData, dateType: "text",
    success: function(data){
        $("#comment").append(data);
        $("#submit").attr({ disabled:false, value:"Shout it!" });
    }
    });
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$("div#comment").prepend('<div class="comment-4"></div>');
```

Or more realistic

```
//something which generates a HTML DOM element
var newComment = ....;
$("div#comment").prepend(newComment);
```

Of course you can use the `prependTo` syntax to if that is more natural for you

```
//something which generates a HTML DOM element
var newComment = ....;
$(newComment).prependTo("div#comment");
```

For more such tricks check the jQuery documentation

[jQuery 1.3 Manipulation API](http://docs.jquery.com/Manipulation)

Answer (score 3):

There are several ways, for example the prependTo method:

```
$('<div class="comment-4"></div>').prependTo('#comment');
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery: [before](http://docs.jquery.com/Manipulation/before#content)

DOM: [insertBefore](http://www.w3.org/TR/1998/REC-DOM-Level-1-19981001/level-one-core.html#ID-952280727)

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are really looking for is a selector for selecting the first comment, no matter what number of them you have (excuse if I am making a poor assumption) then giving it a class greater than the existing class with a name of comment-X where X is some number.

Thus:

```
$("#comment > div[class^=comment-]:first").before('<div class="comment-'+$('div[class^=comment-]').length)+1+'"></div>');
```

EDIT: OH, and the #comment > portion is to select the id of "comment" first, which makes it faster, but not strickly required unless you have more than one comment section such as  somewhere else...

EDIT2: Added the .parent() selector - I typed too fast.
EDIT3: need more coffee, changed .parent().prepend to .before